# PIL's Image.frombuffer expected data length when using ctypes array

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, ctypes

I am using Python, PIL and ctypes to do image manipulation.  As I hacked stuff together, I used PIL's `fromstring` function to get the pixel buffer from ctypes into a PIL object.  I simply iterated over the array, building the python string.

**This works**

```
tx = foo.tx
tx.restype = POINTER(c_ubyte)
result = tx(...args...)

#TODO there must also be a better way to do this
pystr = ""
for i in xrange(w*h*4):
   pystr += result[i]
i = Image.fromstring("RGBA", (w, h), pystr)
i.save("out.png")
```

It wasn't pretty, but it worked. Commented with a TODO and moved on.  After getting the initial plumbing in place, profiling showed significant performance issues with this code block.  Not surprising, I guess.

**This does not work**

Similar to this question: [Pixel manipulation with PIL.Image and ctypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368645/pixel-manipulation-with-pil-image-and-ctypes), I am trying to use `frombuffer()` to get the pixel data into the PIL object more efficiently:

```
tx = foo.tx
tx.restype = POINTER(c_ubyte)
result = tx(...args...)
i = Image.frombuffer('RGBA', (w, h), result, 'raw', 'RGBA', 0, 1)
i.save("out.png")
```

Despite `fromstring` working, using `frombuffer` results in the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 53, in <module>
    i = Image.frombuffer('RGBA', (w, h), res, 'raw', 'RGBA', 0, 1)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1853, in frombuffer
    core.map_buffer(data, size, decoder_name, None, 0, args)
ValueError: buffer is not large enough
```

**Environment**

The buffer is `malloc`'ed in C as:

```
unsigned char *pixels_color = (unsigned char*)malloc((WIDTH*HEIGHT*4)*sizeof(unsigned char*));
```

- The buffer has 4 bytes per pixel for each of the bands RGBA.
- Mac OS X 10.7, python2.7.1, PIL 1.1.7

**Edit**

Based on [eryksun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205580/eryksun)'s comment and answer below, I moved the buffer allocation from the `malloc` in the C library into Python and passed the pointer into C:

```
tx = foo.tx
tx.restype = POINTER(c_ubyte)

pix_clr = (c_ubyte*(w*h*4))()

tx(...args..., pix_clr)
i = Image.frombuffer('RGBA', (w, h), pix_clr, 'raw', 'RGBA', 0, 1)
i.save("out.png")
```

This works as expected.   It still doesn't explain *why* PIL was unhappy with the C-allocated buffer, but this is the better structure for memory management anyway.   Thanks to both ErykSun and HYRY!

Comment: Why is `tx.restype` set to `POINTER(...)` ? Are you returning the pointer, or any other pointer?

Comment: @Unapiedra, yes - the tx function is C and is returning a unsigned char * pointer to the buffer of pixel data.

Comment: Okay. Now, I am confused. why are you passing `pix_clr` into the function as a parameter? And why is the `char * pointer` (or its data) not destroyed after `tx()` has executed?

Comment: Sorry, you're right - been too long since I reviewed that code.  In the "edit" block above, the `tx.restype` line is legacy.  `pix_clr` became a param so I could make the allocation in python and pass it to/from the C lib vs. having it malloc'ed in C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set `tx.restype = POINTER(c_ubyte)`, the resulting ctypes pointer object is a buffer of either 4 or 8 bytes for the *address* of the image buffer. You need to create a ctypes array from this address.

If you know the size ahead of time, you can set `SIZE = WIDTH * HEIGHT * 4; tx.restype = POINTER(c_ubyte * SIZE)`. Otherwise set `tx.restype = POINTER(c_ubyte)`, and cast to the dynamic size, i.e. `size = w * h * 4; pbuf = cast(result, POINTER(c_ubyte * size))`. Either way, you need to dereference the pointer to get at the array. Use either `buf = pbuf[0]` or `buf = pbuf.contents`. Then you can pass `buf` to `Image.frombuffer`.

That said, it's usually simpler to allocate memory using ctypes. This gives you reference-counted memory management instead of having to manually free memory. The following is a toy example.

Assuming a dynamic size, the caller needs to get the image dimensions in order to allocate the array, so I've added a struct that has the width, height, and depth of the image, which gets filled in by the C function `get_image_info`. The function `get_image` receives a pointer to the image array to copy in data.

```
import ctypes

lib = ctypes.CDLL('imgtest.dll')

class ImageInfo(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = (
        ('width', ctypes.c_int),
        ('height', ctypes.c_int),
        ('depth', ctypes.c_int),
    )

pImageInfo = ctypes.POINTER(ImageInfo)
pImage = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ubyte)

lib.get_image_info.argtypes = [pImageInfo]
lib.get_image_info.restype = ctypes.c_int

lib.get_image.argtypes = [pImage]
lib.get_image.restype = ctypes.c_int

imgnfo = ImageInfo()
lib.get_image_info(ctypes.byref(imgnfo))
w, h, d = imgnfo.width, imgnfo.height, imgnfo.depth

imgdata = (w * h * d * ctypes.c_ubyte)()
lib.get_image(imgdata)

from PIL import Image
img = Image.frombuffer('RGBA', (w, h), imgdata, 'raw', 'RGBA', 0, 1)
```

C declarations:

```
typedef struct _ImageInfo {
    int width;
    int height;
    int depth;
} ImageInfo, *pImageInfo;

typedef unsigned char *pImage;

int get_image_info(pImageInfo imgnfo);
int get_image(pImage img);
```

Comment: based on your comment and answer, I moved the buffer allocation from C into Python, and passed into C the pointer to the result buffer.  That works as it should. It still doesn't explain *why*, but at least I can move forward. Thanks for the kick in the right direction!

Comment: To anonymous critic: marking an answer down without providing feedback is all but useless. I can attempt to clarify or improve the answer if you provide feedback.

Answer (score 3):

try the following code:

```
import Image
from ctypes import c_ubyte, cast, POINTER

buf = (c_ubyte * 400)()
pbuf = cast(buf, POINTER(c_ubyte))
pbuf2 = cast(pbuf, POINTER(c_ubyte*400))

img1 = Image.frombuffer("RGBA", (10,10), buf, "raw", "RGBA", 0, 1)
img2 = Image.frombuffer("RGBA", (10,10), pbuf2.contents, "raw", "RGBA", 0, 1)
```

buf is an ubyte array, pbuf is a pointer to ubyte, pbuf2 is a pointer to ubyte[400]. img1 is created from buf directly, img2 is created from pubf2.contents.

your program create image from  an pointer to ubyte, you must cast it to pointer to array, and use contents attribute to get the buffer. So use the following code to convert pointer to array:

```
tmp = cast(result, POINTER(c_ubyte*4*w*h)).contents
Image.frombuffer('RGBA', (w, h), tmp, 'raw', 'RGBA', 0, 1)
```

Comment: your code block to create the images works, but I do not understand where you are headed with the second half; no combinations of `.contents` or `cast()` change the behavior.