# PIL frombuffer() with a pointer

Tags: python, pointers, buffer, python-imaging-library, ctypes

I have a function which returns a pointer to the beginning of a sequence of bytes which correspond to 8 bit greyscale pixels. I'm trying to use PIL's frombuffer() function to create an image out of this. Looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142169/pils-image-frombuffer-expected-data-length-when-using-ctypes-array) I did the following:

```
image_data = (1280*960*ctypes.c_ubyte)()
image_data = Frameptr
im = Image.frombuffer("L", (1280, 960), image_data, "raw", "L", 0, 1)
```

However, I still get this error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "_ctypes/callbacks.c", line 314, in 'calling callback function'
File "C:\Desktop\Program_2013\camera\framegrab.py", line 44, in FrameDataCallBack
im = Image.frombuffer("L", (1280, 960), image_data, "raw", "L", 0, 1)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1853, in frombuffer
core.map_buffer(data, size, decoder_name, None, 0, args)
ValueError: buffer is not large enough
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The first two `image_data` lines have no correlation to one another, other than that the second replaces whatever the first line did.

Comment: Yeah, I realized this. I have tried casting the Frameptr with
    `ctypes.cast(Frameptr,ctypes.POINTER((1280*960)*ctypes.c_ubyte))`

and directly passing it to frombuffer with the contents() from ctypes

Comment: This worked fine for me: `image_data = cast(Frameptr, POINTER(c_ubyte * (1280*960))).contents`